# Determining BigO of a recurrence

Tags: algorithm, function, big-o, discrete-mathematics

```
T (1) = c    
T (n) = T (n/2) + dn
```

How would I determine BigO of this quickly?

Comment: To determine BigO quickly you have to have some experience. To achieve that you have to practise.

Comment: Well ok whats any method at least

Comment: Do you have any other information? I would expect there to be some starting condition. Like `T(0) = ...` or `T(1) = ...`

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, but what is `dn`? Is that a constant multiplied by `n`?

Comment: Ok I added the initial condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use repeated backsubstitution and find the pattern. An example [here](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus4/html/page41.html).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what `dn` is, but assuming you mean a constant multiplied by `n`:

[According to Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28n%29+%3D+f%28n%2F2%29+%2B+c+%2a+n), the recurrence equation solution for:

```
f(n) = f(n / 2) + cn
```

is:

```
f(n) = 2c(n - 1) + c1
```

which would make this `O(n)`.

Comment: Oh wow wolfram does this too..thats crazy..but Id need to be able to do this kind of stuff on a test

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "be able to do this kind of stuff on a test"?

Comment: I want to be able to determine bigO of this function

Comment: The BigO appears to be `O(n)`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ani: He wants to know the *technique*, not the *answer*.  (Isn't that obvious?)

Comment: @fprime, @j_random_hacker: On re-reading, yes it does seem obvious now. Sorry, I missed that. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the recurrence part of the relationship is the T(n/2) part, which is in effect halving the value of n each time.

Thus you will need approx. (log2 n) steps to get to the termination condition, hence the overall cost of the algorithm is O(log2 n). You can ignore the dn part as is it a constant-time operation for each step.

Note that as stated, the problem won't necessarily terminate since halving an arbitrary value of n repeatedly is unlikely to exactly hit 1. I suspect that the T(n/2) part should actually read T(floor (n / 2)) or something like that in order to ensure that this terminates.

Comment: Hm I think you got into the same trap as I did. I'm so used to see BigO in the context of a computational complexity, that it was my first thought as well. But it's quite possible that the problem is in fact to determine the BigO for the solution of that recurrence :)

Comment: Having said that, I'm pretty sure you can compute the solution in O(1) if you are allowed to solve the recurrence.

Comment: Yes :), but I suspect the question might be about the limiting behaviour of the solution, not of a computational complexity of computing T(n) given the solution. I might be wrong of course. Some say that the first impulse is the best :)

Answer (score 0):

use master's theorem 
see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

By the way, the asymptotic behaviour of your recurrence is O(n) assuming d is positive and sufficiently smaller than n (size of problem)